# ArrayListMultimap Vs ArrayList , which have the high performance?

Tags: java, performance, collections, guava

In my application, I'm using `ArrayList(java.util)` for storing bulk of customized data and processing. But it causes the process delay when use continuously in a scheduled manner. So I would like to switch to some other.

Does `ArrayListMultimap(com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap)` have higher performance than `ArrayList`? Or any other open source collection frameworks that have better performance than `ArrayList`?

Comment: You can improve the `ArrayList` performance by setting the initial size to a higher value. The major cost when using `ArrayList` is incrementing the backing array size because it has to create a new array with the new size and pass all the values from the old array to the new one. If you don't know the size of your data (or don't have an estimate), then you could move to `LinkedList`.

Comment: `ArrayListMultimap` has a totally different aim to `ArrayList`. Are you trying to store a list, or a map from keys to lists?

Comment: Yes. But if you don't want a random access other wise `LinkedList` will have  `O(n)` for Random access.

Comment: Where/when is it slow? What does the data look like? As others have pointed out these are 2 fairly different data structures. Is it slow on insert, lookup, delete, or something else?

Comment: If you keep adding and removing items a queue structure might be more appropriate.

Comment: There are cases where `LinkedList` is fast than other structures, but they're extremely rare. You'd need to perform a lot of deletions  or insertions at random positions, the former can be done via `Iterator`, the latter only via index which implies sequential search. As usually reads are far more common, `LinkedList` is nearly never the right choice.

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza, Thanks... after setting the size, performance is improved...

Comment: @ Jon Skeet , then what's the actual purpose of ArrayListMultimap ...

Comment: @JinjuJoseph See the [javadoc of `Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html): it's like a `Map` with multiple values per key (nicer to use than `Map<K, Collection<V>>`). `ArrayListMultimap` is an implementation where the collections of values are `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of operations do you perform more? You could use any java profiler build statistics, in case you are not sure.

List is good for storing objects, iterating. It's not a good idea to use j.u.ArrayList to perform remove, contains, etc. operations, as they would be O(n). Moving to Map or Set should be done carefully, for example, you cannot use mutable objects as keys, you have to define equals and hashCode functions, you have to worry about caching hashCode value if calculations are heavy.

In order to give you the best answer you should point to set of operations you run on lists.

Cheers